# Mirror individual words in a sentence, but not the sentence itself

Tags: python

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can create a `function` which takes in words from the standard `input` and `prints` them `mirrored`?

For example:

Input:

```
day time you is
```

Output:

```
yad emit ouy si
```

Comment: Please show your attempts at creating this function

Comment: You should give it a try and if you get stuck you come with a specific doubt. We can't do it for you, but we can look at what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `generator` to loop through each `word` in the `string` and reverse it. To reverse it, we use advanced `slicing` with `-1` as the `step` value. And then we want to join all the reversed words together with a `space` in between each word. We can do this with `str.join`.

Putting the above together, we get the `function`:

```
def mirror(s):
    return ' '.join(w[::-1] for w in s.split())
```

examples:

```
>>> mirror("day time you is")
'yad emit uoy si'
>>> mirror("hello how are you")
'olleh woh era uoy'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mirrow(stringToMirror) :
     stringToMirrorList = StringToMirror.split(" ")
     for x in stringToMirrorList :
         print x(::-1)  + " "
```